# Equations with operations next to each line

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

I basically want to type a derivation of a specific mathematical formula with the operations that have been done in each line, for e.g.:

```
  U = R * I      |:R
U/R = I
```

Handwritten it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What would I do if my "final solution" is a mixture of multiple answers?

Comment: Probably choose the one that was the most helpful in getting to your final solution. `:)`

Answer (score 8):

Use the `align` environment (within `amsmath` package):

```
\begin{align*}
  U          &=RI    &  &\div R\\
  \frac{U}{R}&=I     &  &
\end{align*}
```

The first and third `&` align the sets of equations (say first and second column), while the second sign `&` separates the "columns" of equations

Comment: Same answer with better explanations ! You should add a `*` in `\end{align}` to make it perfect.

Comment: You shouldn't use `align` (or `align*`) if you have more than one ampersand. In this case, you should use `alignat` (or `alignat*`) and specify the number of alignment points.

Comment: Why not? It does the job. And you do not have to add manual horizontal space

Comment: @SvendTveskæg. The `align` environments are designed to be used with more than two ampersands.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `align*` environment:

```
\begin{align*}
  U&=RI & \div R\\
  \frac{U}{R}&=I &
\end{align*}
```

Comment: It is better to use two `&`'s before the 'operation/comment', like in Dox's answer.

Comment: @jmc. Why ? This will align the comments on their left.

Comment: @V.Rosetto — Exactly.

Comment: @jmc. Somehow, it seems more agreeable to me to have the comments right-aligned. A matter of taste, anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  && U &= R \cdot I \qquad \vert\ :R \\
  \ArrowBetweenLines
  && \frac{U}{R} &= I
\end{alignat*}
\vspace{4ex}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  && U &= R \cdot I \\
  \text{(Divide by $R$)}\Updownarrow \quad &&& \\
  && \frac{U}{R} &= I
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Of the two approaches, I would use the bottom one.

Answer (score 1):

What I have found useful is a big slash which shows you want to operate on both sides which is `\bigg/`. It also works pretty well with `\qquad` or `align`.

Solutions:

```
\begin{align*}
   U&=RI & \bigg/ :R\\
   \frac{U}{R}&=I &
\end{align*}
```

[image]

or (here `/:R` will be included in centring the equation which might not be desired)

```
\begin{equation}
  U = RI \qquad \bigg/ :R
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac{U}{R} = I
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Original answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240446/how-to-get-a-large-division-symbol)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the package `witharrows`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{witharrows}

\begin{document}
$\begin{WithArrows}
U           & = RI \Arrow{division by $R$} \\
\frac{U}{R} & = I 
\end{WithArrows}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]