# How to get a large division symbol?

Tags: math-mode, align, ieeetran

I'm using:

```
\documentclass[journal,transmag]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
 something&\left(\sum_{n}\right.\nonumber\\
&\quad\left.\vphantom{\sum_{n}}+y\right)/\left(x\right)^2.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

With `\vphantom{\sum_{n}}` I get the big right parenthesis in the second line which is what I want. How can I get a larger division symbol as well?

Comment: Larger how? Would it be possible for you to include an image of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I understand it's only an example, but your usage of `\left` and `\right` is wrong.

```
\begin{align}
 something &\biggl(\sum_{n}\nonumber\\
&\quad+y\biggr) \bigg/ x^2.
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: Why does your code complain in my Tex? :| It says "missing } inserted", "extra \right", "missing \endgroup inserted" etc...

Comment: @Alenanno I forgot to remove a `\right.`

Comment: Ah ok, fixed. :)

Comment: Can you explain why using `\left` and `\right` as OP did is wrong? I also learned such usage from some references. I know you always have good reasons for your recommends, so I am very curious now.

Comment: @TheGreatSeo one cannot have `\left` in one row of an alignment and `\right` in another one. Anyway, don’t overuse them, because they tend to make larger delimiters than necessary.

Answer (score 2):

To get the scaled division symbol, you probably want to use the `\left` ... `\middle` ... `\right` construction:

```
\begin{align}
 something&\left(\sum_{n}\right.\nonumber\\
&\quad\left.\left.\vphantom{\sum_{n}}+y\right)\middle/\left(x\right)^2\right..
\end{align}
```

[image: latex output]